# React-apollo: Change variables without refetching in a polling query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

Is there a way so we can change the variables in a query without refetching?

My use case is when you have a polling query and you want to skip or include a part of the query according to a user's action.

for example

```js
const USER_STATS = gql`
  query userStats($withDetailedStats:Boolean!) {
    user {
      stats {
        ...stats
      }
      detailedStats@include(if:$withDetailedStats) {
        ...detailedStats
      }
    }
  }
`;

class Example extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <Query
        query={query} 
        variables={{ withDetailedStats: false }} 
        pollInterval={5000}
      >
        {
          ({ data, refetch, loading }) => {
            if (loading) { return 'Loading...'; }
            const { user } = data;
            return (
              <div>
                <div>{user && user.stats}</div>
                <Button onClick={this.openModal}>More Details</Button>
                <Modal
                  onOpen={() => { refetch({ withDetailedStats: true }); }} 
                  onClose={() => { setVariablesWithoutRefetching({ withDetailedStats: false }); }}
                >
                  <div>{user && user.detailedStats}</div>
                </Modal>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
      </Query>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I would also appreciate knowing the answer to this.

Comment: I would recommend digging into the source code. To my knowledge, this is not possible but to verify this one would have to look at the implementation.

Comment: To follow up, I never found a solution to this, we ended up changing our API functioned to work around this issue.